# How to insert latin data into a Snowflake Table

Tags: sql, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

We have a scenario, that we need to insert some special characters coming from file to the Snowflake table.

**For exp:**

```
emp_id| emp_name
110|Famille immédiate
```

As the snowflake only allow UTF-8 format, when running the dml operation the data is not getting inserted into the table and throwing an error.

Have tried updating the file format command but no solution yet.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT DB.LayOut01_FORMAT TYPE = CSV FIELD_DELIMITER = '|' SKIP_HEADER = 1 ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE VALIDATE_UTF8 = FAlSE
```

What will be changes required to allow special charectors into the table as it is coming from source file ??

**Insert Statement:**

```
INSERT INTO DB.EMP_T ( emp_id, emp_name) 
SELECT
(temp.$1)  AS emp_id , (temp.$2)  AS emp_name 
from
$AZURE_FILE_STORAGE_LOCATION (file_format => DB.LayOut01_FORMAT, pattern=>'filename.csv') temp
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100144 (22000): 01a99ebe-0c03-0c00-0000-e3d54g4w345a: Invalid UTF8 detected in string 
'Art/Ni0xE80x630x65.

**Input data is like : "Art/Nièce"**

Comment: Try re-creating file format by completely removing REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE VALIDATE_UTF8 = FAlSE. This is the only thing I found was giving error, removing its working for me.

Comment: were you able to insert special characters data aswell into the table??

Comment: Yes, its working fine for special chars too. The only error I get on using REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS and VALIDATE_UTF8 in format is - "sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100038 (22018): Numeric value '110|Famille immédiate' is not recognized". Works fine without those format options.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is the only format for semi-structured data, but for structured you can insert data with different encodings.

Use on the file format the ENCODING parameter and set it to IS-8859-1, like:

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT ... ENCODING='ISO-8859-1'
```

For more information have a look [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html).